# CREATE MODEL with Redshift: Correlation

Tags: amazon-redshift, amazon-sagemaker

how can to see the correlations regarding the target column of the trained models? Is there an option in the Redshift query editor oder Sagemaker?
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

you can refer to the blog [Build regression models with Amazon Redshift ML](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/build-regression-models-with-amazon-redshift-ml/) for instructions on using a sample stored procedure that will calculate correlations with the target variable in Redshift ML.

If you need just the stored procedure, it is also available in GitHub here - https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/blob/master/src/StoredProcedures/sp_correlation.sql

Comment: Is it possible to see the feature importance regarding the original feature names? With the output model i only can see some feature names f0 to f500 but originally there were only 20 columns